# PDF con formato corrupto desde una cadena en Base-64

Tags: c#, codificación

Tengo una cadena en Base-64 que es correcta puesto que está verificada en una web que presta el servicio de prueba para convertir una cadena en Base-64 en PDF. El archivo que genera se abre y se visualiza correctamente.

El problema lo tengo cuando el PDF lo genero por programación. En ese caso los pasos que doy son:

1. Convertir la cadena en Base-64 en una cadena normal con codificación UTF-8.
2. Convertir esa cadena en una matriz de bytes.
3. Crear el archivo PDF pasando la matriz de bytes como parámetro.

De la forma siguiente.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   

string base64 = "aquí la cadena en Base-64";

//El punto 1:

     string cadena = ConPlano(base64);

//El punto 2:

     Byte[] matrizBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cadena);

//El punto 3:

     CreaPDF (matrizBytes);

}


    public void CreaPDF (Byte[] matrizBytes) {
    
        File.WriteAllBytes((HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "pdf/pdfnuevo.pdf", matrizBytes);
    
    }
 public string ConPlano(string Base64)
            {
                Byte[] r;
                
                r = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64);
                String cadena = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(r);
                return cadena;
            }
```

El archivo se crea sin problemas pero no se puede abrir. He comprobado que convirtiendo de nuevo la matriz de bytes del punto 2 en una cadena en Base-64 no se corresponde con la primera (string base64). Ese es el problema. Debe de producirse algún problema en uno de los tres pasos. Los reviso una y otra vez y no veo en cuál. He probado con todas las codificaciones pero nunca termina generándose un PDF correcto. Sospecho que puede estar el problema en la funcion *ConPlano*

Comment: Tu código tiene mucho ruido (transformaciones innecesarias), te recomiendo que lo simplifiques borrando el punto 1 y 2, y en el 3 colocas `CreaPDF (Convert.FromBase64String(base64))`, además agrega un string en base64 valido para poder reproducir el problema

Comment: Hola Yussef. De acuerdo, pruebo la simplificación y si sigue sin funcionar pongo una cadena válida. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Solucionado con tu simplificación!! Ahora el PDF se abre y es correcto. Muchísimas gracias Yussef.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que es más complicado generar un pdf que un texto plano, no solo por la codificación, para eso si lo quieres hacer sencillo puedes usar un programa como [PdfSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpFirstSteps.ashx) que te lo pone facil. Si miras el ejemplo abriendo con notepad o notepad++ el que te genero la web muy probablemente tenga mas cosas que solo el string codificado aunque no se vea en el adobepdf

Ejemplo de un pdf creado con word vs el de tu codigo con la misma palabra:
Word:
[image: Word]
EL tuyo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De acuerdo rexxarcat, entiendo. El problema es que necesito convertir la cadena en Base64 en PDF. Se trata de una respuesta desde AutoFirma, y que representa un PDF firmado. ¿No hay alguna forma para hacerlo así? Yo empleo la biblioteca iText para crear archivos PDF pero en este punto tengo que hacerlo a partir de la cadena Base-64. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Se ha solucionado con la solución de Yussef. Muchas gracias rexxarcat!

Answer (score 0):

El código correcto teniendo en cuenta la respuesta de Yussef es el siguiente:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   
//siendo base64 una cadena válida de un archivo PDF va a funcionar

string base64 = "aquí la cadena en Base-64";

     CreaPDF (Convert.FromBase64String(base64));

}


    public void CreaPDF (Byte[] matrizBytes) {
    
        File.WriteAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "pdf/pdfnuevo.pdf", matrizBytes);
    
    }
```